# Hashing and Password Cracking

Tags: cryptanalysis, finite-field, password-hashing, password-based-encryption

I was playing a game on cryptography where I encountered this problem:

> Hashed Value of password:  24 109 76 35 22 94 83 25 106 104 73 87 56 38 56 50 10
> 92 58 84 44 88 24 112 125 121 125 43 122 55 106 54
>
> The password is made of letters between 'f' and 'u'. The password is
> in alphabetical order.  For hashing, the password is viewed as a
> sequence of numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_m$ in the field $F_{127}$. The
> $i^{th}$ number of the hashed sequence equals $x_1^{i-1} + x_2^{i-1}$ +
> ... + $x_m^{i-1}$. As we can see, there are 32 such numbers for i = 1 to
> 32."

My approach to the following problem is as follows:

- As there are 16 letters from f to u, each letter is mapped with integer 0 to 15.
- The length of the password is 24 as the first hashed value is 24 and hashing sequence for the same is  $x_1^{0} + x_2^{0}$ + ... + $x_m^{0}$.
- The sum of the numbers from the integer mapped password mod 127 will be 109.
- Multiple equations can be formed like above.

Doing brute force to retrieve the password seems computationally infeasible. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: HINT: You might like to read up on [Elementary Symmetric Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and [Vieta's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: okay thank you, let me look into them